# I need help with confidence because i have worked out hard for over a month and a half and still no weight loss on scale?

Tags: workout

Okay, here's the deal. I have lost a lot of weight. And, kind of gained a little of it back. I am only 19 and wanted to lose about 10-15 pounds. I would be happy with 10lbs really. I go to the gym every day and do cardio for no less than 45 minutes. On every day, I do weight training on different body parts: legs/arms/abs/butt. I don't see ANY difference in the scale. No weight loss, no weight gain. I feel so freaking discouraged because I devote myself fully by eating healthy and getting my exercise in DAILY for almost two months now and absolutely nothing has happened. Maybe I have lost weight but gained muscle and that has caused me to remain the same weight? PLEASE HELP :)

Answer (score 2):

To lose weight the rule is simple: **[Eat Less, Move More.](https://examine.com/nutrition/what-should-i-eat-for-weight-loss/)**

You clearly have the "Move more" sorted but it's not clear that you are eating less. Healthy food does not necessarily mean less calories. It is possible to gain weight eating a mostly healthy diet, staying at a caloric surplus.

If you were untrained before starting it is entirely possible you gained muscle and lost fat, the proof would be in photos (or a DEXA body scan), not on the scale.

2 Months is not that long a time, for losing weight it is recommended (and should be possible to achieve) that you aim for 1-2lb loss per week. At lower body-fat levels it takes longer to lose weight but the method is the same.

For more information on why 'healthy' calories are the same as 'unhealthy' calories see my detailed answer [here on why "a calorie is a calorie"](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/33505/19738)

---

Footnote: There *may* be a medical reason why you cannot lose weight easily, if you are concerned this is the case you should ask your Doctor/GP and not people on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Muscle weighs more than fat. If you're lifting weights you should expect to gain muscle which would increase weight. But if you're doing cardio you should expect to burn fat which would be a loss of weight. So if those two ideas are put together maybe your weight wouldn't change at all? If your strength is increasing(you are able to lift more weight or do more reps of the same weight that you started with)you're probably increasing muscle. If you can do cardio longer before getting winded than when you started, you're probably burning the fat properly. Don't let the scale be validation that your efforts are working. Real diets take a while to start showing good results too. Stick with your diet for about 2 more months then reevaluate.

Comment: This is just not true. I have successfully gained weight while running 30k per week at 5-6min/km average.

Comment: True. I'm not saying you can't gain weight if you do cardio. I'm saying that you can't judge fat loss and muscle gain fairly from a number on the scale.

Comment: Muscle doesn't weigh more than fat.  One pound of fat is the same weight as one pound of muscle.  That being said, 1 lb of fat takes up about 22% more physical space than one pound of muscle.  http://www.thespartanwarrior.com/post/9967667225/musclevsfat

Answer (score 0):

I can personally tell you that to get your metabolism out of a catatonic state is not easy. You have started excercising and this is good but for long term weight loss you have to eventually start feeding your body in a new manner. Your body is waking up. You are busy telling it that you expect it to change.

You will find that if you keep on exercising you will devlop an appetite that is unlike the one you had before. If you listen to your body and eat when you are hungry you will start feeding it in a better manner. Keep to the proteins, if you do eat carbs make sure it is complex carbs, avoid filler.

Also working out six days a week is not good. A days rest is just as good as a days work. You may find that your muscle is not building because you dont give it any chance to build. You need rest in between workouts as well. More is not always better.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to lose weight but my advice is to set non body image goals and find exercises you enjoy most. For example being able to lift higher weights or do a certain yoga move. Making excercise something you do for you and not your body image will keep you heathier as it becomes a habit. You're doing great ! A number on the scale is just that.